# Javascript included the word undefined as part of the outupt

Tags: javascript, html, output, undefined

```
    var i = 0;
    var txt = 'Christmas Family Service - Sunday 19th December at 11:45 am.  Come along to Bethany Evangelical Church and find out about the real meaning of Christmas.'; /* The text */
    var speed = 50; /* The speed/duration of the effect in milliseconds */
    
    function typeWriter() {
      if (i < txt.length) {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += txt.charAt(i);
        i++;
        setTimeout(typeWriter, speed);
      }
    }


<div class="announce">

<p id="demo">
<script>

document.write(typeWriter());
</script>

</p>

</div>
```

C**undefined** hristmas Family Service - Sunday 19th December at 11:45 am. Come along to Bethany Evangelical Church and find out about the real meaning of Christmas.

Comment: When you do `document.write` it adds the argument to the document. In your case the result of `typeWriter()` which is `undefined` (because `typeWriter` doesn't return anything)

Answer (score 4):

Your

```
<p id="demo">
  <script>
    document.write(typeWriter());
  </script>
</p>
```

inserts the return value of calling `typeWriter` into that `#demo` element - but the function does not return anything.

There's [no real good reason](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/why-is-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice#:%7E:text=It%20can%20block%20your%20page,of%20the%20page%20that%20follow.) to use `document.write` anyway. All you need to do is call the function, not use `document.write` as well.

```js
var i = 0;
var txt = 'Christmas Family Service - Sunday 19th December at 11:45 am.  Come along to Bethany Evangelical Church and find out about the real meaning of Christmas.'; /* The text */
var speed = 50; /* The speed/duration of the effect in milliseconds */

function typeWriter() {
  if (i < txt.length) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += txt.charAt(i);
    i++;
    setTimeout(typeWriter, speed);
  }
}

typeWriter();
```

```html
<div class="announce">
  <p id="demo"></p>
</div>
```

Fixing other parts of the code:

- You only need to select the element once, not every time the loop runs
- `.innerHTML` should only be used when deliberately inserting HTML markup - with plain text, `.textContent` is faster, safer, and more predictable

```js
let i = 0;
const txt = 'Christmas Family Service - Sunday 19th December at 11:45 am.  Come along to Bethany Evangelical Church and find out about the real meaning of Christmas.'; /* The text */
const speed = 50; /* The speed/duration of the effect in milliseconds */

const demo = document.getElementById("demo");
function typeWriter() {
  if (i < txt.length) {
    demo.textContent += txt[i];
    i++;
    setTimeout(typeWriter, speed);
  }
}

typeWriter();
```

```html
<div class="announce">
  <p id="demo"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: It would also be a good idea to cache the element outside of the function, and use `textContent` instead of `innerHTML`.

Comment: Thank you for the swift help with this javascript.  If I cut and paste the code from the snippet I get no output on my html.   I have referenced the javascript with :  <script src="js/typeWriter.js"></script>

Comment: @Gvee Make sure you're inserting the script *after* the `#demo` element, or use `defer` tag. If that's not the issue, check your browser console for errors (as always)

Comment: defer tag worked well.   Thanks for the help.